# Run two queries on the same table at once?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to retrieve distinct records from a column in a mysql table and then retrieve data from each row that the distinct records show up in. Sorry if this isn't very clear. I can elaborate if necessary.

EDIT:

```
+------+------+-----+
|  ip  | hits | day |
+------+------+-----+
| ip1  | 23   | 52  |
+------+------+-----+
| ip2  | 28   | 50  |
+------+------+-----+
| ip1  | 46   | 54  |
+------+------+-----+
| ip4  | 15   | 55  |
+------+------+-----+
| ip2  | 12   | 52  |
+------+------+-----+
```

I need to select distinct ips, then for each ip add up all the hits for that ip.

Comment: If you show the structure or name some of the columns, you'll be able to get some more specific SQL.

Comment: By "distinct" do you mean values which only occur once? Please do elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT SUM(`hits`) AS `total_hits`, `ip`
    FROM `ips`
GROUP BY `ip`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I'm not entirely sure how to use that SQL. I've added more to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you need two queries, you just need to select distinct rows for the first column and then use a where clause for the additional data.